# Change directory of terminal unless one is specified

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I want to have my default directory be `~/` unless there is another one specified by a command. Like, when I right click and choose "Open in Terminal", I want it to be the correct directory, but if I just do <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> I want it to stay at `~/` instead. My terminal keeps defaulting to `/usr/share/budgie-desktop/keycontrol` instead of where I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `/usr/share/budgie-desktop/keycontrol` your `$HOME` directory? Check with `getent passwd $USER | cut -d: -f6`.  Use `vipw` to edit the 6th field (`HOME` directory) of `/etc/passwd`, log out & in.

Is there a `cd /usr/share/budgie-desktop/keycontrol` in your `$HOME/.bashrc`? Remove it, or add

```
cd "$HOME"
```

to the file.

Comment: I updated the home directory and logged out and in, and now it works correctly. Thanks a bunch!